# Isn't the picture on Wikipedia about Weyl Chambers wrong?

Tags: lie-groups, coxeter-groups

[Wikipedia's article on Weyl groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group) shows an example of a root system and the corresponding fundamental chambers (in my understanding, also known as fundamental regions or fundamental domains). In this picture, the fundamental chambers contain some of the roots. I would expect the roots to determine the walls of the fundamental chambers and, therefore, not be contained in them.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: A root $\alpha$ lies in a wall if and only if there is another root $\beta$ such that $\left< \alpha , \beta \right>=0$. There is no reason that should be true for a given root in a given system. Indeed, the picture you refer to is of the root system $A_2$, and no two roots in that system are orthogonal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture is ok, I think that you might be misinterpreting or misremembering the way in which the roots determine the walls of the chambers. Recall the definition of the Weyl Chambers: A *Weyl Chamber* is a connected component of $E\setminus\bar{H}$, where $E$ is your underlying Euclidean space, and $\bar{H}$ is the union of the hyperplanes that are perpendicular to the roots (i.e., a hyperplane $H_\alpha$ in $\bar{H}$ is perpendicular to the line formed by joining $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ for some root $\alpha$).

In the case of the root system $A_2$ (the Wikipedia picture), each hyperplane $H_\alpha$ will avoid all other roots. As Asal said, a root $\alpha$ will be in a wall iff there is a root $\beta$ such that $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle = 0$ (i.e., imagining the roots as lines, they're perpendicular). This will not always happen, but it is possible. For example, in the root system $G_2$ some roots will indeed lie in some of the walls (in fact, in $G_2$ every root lies in a wall):
[image]

Comment: I was indeed being misled. The examples I've looked at were all 2-dimensional and they had the said property. That settles it. Thanks.